# Styled components SSR concerns when using nth-child and similar selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, emotion

I am currently working on a gatsby project using theme-ui which uses emotion under the hood. Emotion's SSR has issues like FOUC when using some css selectors (e.g owl selector `(* + *)`, `nth-child()` selector etc) because of the way it performs hydration (see [Problems surrounding SSR injection of  and unreliability of :first-child selectors](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1178)). Does styled-components also suffer from same issues?